# Creating a rolling ball

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, animation, uiimageview

How would you make it so a ball (UIImageView) "rolls" on a solid platform (ground) continuously? I am brand new to animation on the iPhone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the animation features built into UIImageView.  You provide all the frames of the rolling ball animation as images in an array, and feed that to the UIImageView.  It will then play those images in order, kind of like an animated gif.

I suppose you could then just put the UIImageView on top of a background that moves (or doesn't?) to give the illusion that the ball is rolling.

You might also find the [Cocos2d framework](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) helpful.

Comment: Why not use *UIView*'s `transform` property and add some rotation? Much easier than providing a bunch of sprites. Also, smells like homework.

Comment: Hahaha nope, it's not homework; I'm not even old enough to take any computer science classes yet that I know of. Thanks for your help, though!